# Swift - How to get Segmented control to lock at top of screen

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, swift4, uisegmentedcontrol

I have a UI ImageView and a few labels on the top of the screen, followed by a segmented control, with a tableView underneath.

How would you go about making the segmented control lock at the top of the screen, if the user scrolls down in the tableView?

Should everything be embedded in a scroll view, even though tableViews already have scrolling?

Comment: Try adding the segment control in the header of the tableview.

Comment: And you would put the labels and image view in a separate cell too?

Comment: separate section ..... labels and image view are above the segment control right..??  In that scenario keep it in different section above and then in separate section work on segment control below the label and image view.

Comment: Yes, the labels and image view are above the segmented control

Answer (score 1):

Set number of section in :

```
func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 2
}
```

Then in :

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    switch section {
    case 0:
        return 0
    default:
        return "According to segment conrtrol height"
    }
}
```

for first section header height will be 0 and for second section header height according to the segment control height.

Then design the UI for segment control in :

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    switch section {
    case 0:
        return nil
    default:
        "Create your UI"
}
```